# Javascript failing on staging environment (jQuery slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi there as for a project I run a staging environment.

I have been busy with a jQuery slider (easySlider 1.7) and I have been running into some strange behaviour in my development environment (creating double html instances of next button and numerics) after a while I figured out I had included the easySlider.js 2 times.

so now this is fixed on development! but after I push it to my Staging environment it still contains double instances?

I have tried the following: 
overwrite the staging.rb settings to development to see if this is were the issue is.
clear my browser cache and clear server cache.

any idea on how I could sync my development to staging properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you did not precompile your assets after that change so in your `/public/assets` folder you still have the old files.

Go into your server and run `rake assets:precompile` to see if the problem goes away.

In case you are using capistrano also make sure to load the assets recipes in your `deploy.rb`:

```
 load 'deploy/assets'
```

Are you even using asset precompilation in your staging environment? (Meaning asset.debug is true) .. I had an issue once where I deployed to a environment where rails by default did not merge all JavaScripts into application.js but included them like in development. Since capistrano still executed assets:precompile on the server I ended up with an application.js file that contained all of the JS files and each of the source files too. I simply had to delete `public/assets` in that case

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Tigraine I tried your method although it did not make any difference. any more good thoughts?

Comment: Thanks got it running found out that my staging.rb was a bad copy of production.rb which still included dual js files. after recompiling it worked thanks